# How to prevent bots using REST API calls to register new users from an mobile app?

Tags: django, security, rest, django-registration, tastypie

I want to write a backend application with REST API in django-tastypie for mobile apps.

If i am sending POST data (user-object) to e.g. `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/register/` from within my mobile app to register a new user, everybody who knows the url can register new users and blow my database. How do i prevent this? Is using a REST-API for user registration a wrong approach? Can someone point me to in the right direction? I dont want to use OAuth for logging in my users.

Comment: Er... require the user to answer some kind of [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA)?  It's never pretty but is the de facto convention.

Comment: I dont think captchas are the right way to go in mobile apps. habe you ever seen this when registering to twitter,facebook,instagram etc on your mobile device?

Comment: Have never tested TBH, Though the last time I checked the Facebook desktop registration process a mobile number is more or less a requirement - and they have a system in place that text's you a 4 digit code to verify that it's your device - CAPTCHAs the cheap and cheerful option (what's wrong with only showing one if more than one request from the same IP in a short space of time? That way you don't inconvenience anyone that doesn't appear to be abusing the service).

Comment: How about adding a "honeypot" hidden field that a human won't fill out but a bot probably would? If the honeypot is "full", meaning it has a value, then the form is not valid.

Comment: You can add a application key to only allowed the authorized application to access your resources.

Comment: @Lifecube what's to prevent the attacker from using your application key?

Comment: 2 parts need to be considered. 1) mobile apps need to protect the key in secure way, either by function from system or implemented by itself. 2) server side needs to implement the key management function, which allows the developer to renew the application key, in case it's unfortunately obtained by attacker.

Comment: You could take a look some mbaas providers, they provide the functions in their solution.

Answer (score 0):

everything depends on how securely you can store data on the mobile application...

if you are pretty sure that you can have something securely stored on the mobile phones with your app, the simplest solution is to set-up certificate authentication on your frontend server, in such a case every connection without proper certificate will fail

this is quite simple solution that does not require any changes to your backend code, only small change to clients (to use certificate)